# Safari Push Notifications authenticationToken

Tags: safari, auth-token, safari-push-notifications

I need make Safari Push Notifications.

I use guides:

https://medium.com/anantha-krishnan-k-g/safari-push-notifications-ec171bdf6ead

http://samuli.hakoniemi.net/how-to-implement-safari-push-notifications-on-your-website/

and

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NotificationProgrammingGuideForWebsites/PushNotifications/PushNotifications.html

I not understand one thing. Where i get `authenticationToken` for `website.json`?

Tell me please. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's is not important if you serve the zip as a static file. Insert anything above 16 characters.

Users are identified with a device token.